# check if one element in array has value

Tags: php, arrays

i have an array **$error** which tells me if any of my post vars produced an error or not:

```
Array
(
    [pers_anrede] =>  1
    [pers_titel] => 1
    [pers_vorname] => 
    [pers_nachname] => 
    [pers_vorwahl] => 1 
    [pers_telefon] => 1
    [pers_email] => 
)
```

(where 1 means that the element has an error)

what is the most effective way to find out whether any errors at all are present? if all elements in my array are set to 0, i want to continue doing something else. if there is at least one error present, i want to display a general error message.

Comment: are you trying to search a value in an array? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2693310/search-for-values-in-nested-array

Comment: the values can only be 1 or 0. if there is at least one value of "1" i want to say something like "there has been an error" ... if however no errors where detected (meaning all elements in the array will be 0), everything is fine.

Answer (score 3):

```
if( in_array(1, $error) ) {
    //we have at least one error
}
```