# PHP Array Search for specfic value

Tags: php, arrays, search

This is the result of my $array:

```
    Array ( [row] => Array ( [Field] => product_id [Type] => int(11) [Null] => NO [Key] => PRI [Default] => [Extra] => auto_increment ) [rows] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [Field] => product_id [Type] => int(11) [Null] => NO [Key] => PRI [Default] => [Extra] => auto_increment ) [1] => Array ( [Field] => model [Type] => varchar(64) [Null] => NO [Key] => [Default] => [Extra] => ) [2] => Array ( [Field] => sku [Type] => varchar(64) [Null] => NO [Key] => [Default] => [Extra] => ) [3] => Array ( [Field] => upc [Type] => varchar(12) [Null] => NO [Key] => [Default] => [Extra] => ) [4] => Array ( [Field] => ean [Type] => varchar(14) [Null] => NO [Key] => [Default] => [Extra] => ) [5] => Array ( [Field] => jan [Type] => varchar(13) [Null] => NO [Key] => [Default] => [Extra] => ) [6] => Array ( [Field] => isbn [Type] => varchar(13) [Null] => NO [Key] => [Default] => [Extra] => ) [7] => Array ( [Field] => mpn [Type] => varchar(64) [Null] => NO [Key] => [Default] => [Extra] => ) [8] => Array ( [Field] => location [Type] => varchar(128) [Null] => NO [Key] => [Default] => [Extra] => ) [9] => Array ( [Field] => quantity [Type] => int(4) [Null] => NO [Key] => [Default] => 0 [Extra] => ) [10] => Array ( [Field] => stock_status_id [Type] => int(11) [Null] => NO [Key] => [Default] => [Extra] => ) [11] => Array ( [Field] => image [Type] => varchar(255) [Null] => YES [Key] => [Default] => [Extra] => ) [12] => Array ( [Field] => manufacturer_id [Type] => int(11) [Null] => NO [Key] => [Default] => [Extra] => ) [13] => Array ( [Field] => shipping [Type] => tinyint(1) [Null] => NO [Key] => [Default] => 1 [Extra] => ) [14] => Array ( [Field] => price [Type] => decimal(15,4) [Null] => NO [Key] => [Default] => 0.0000 [Extra] => ) [15] => Array ( [Field] => points [Type] => int(8) [Null] => NO [Key] => [Default] => 0 [Extra] => ) [16] => Array ( [Field] => tax_class_id [Type] => int(11) [Null] => NO [Key] => [Default] => [Extra] => ) [17] => Array ( [Field] => date_available [Type] => date [Null] => NO [Key] => [Default] => [Extra] => ) [18] => Array ( [Field] => weight [Type] => decimal(15,8) [Null] => NO [Key] => [Default] => 0.00000000 [Extra] => ) [19] => Array ( [Field] => weight_class_id [Type] => int(11) [Null] => NO [Key] => [Default] => 0 [Extra] => ) [20] => Array ( [Field] => length [Type] => decimal(15,8) [Null] => NO [Key] => [Default] => 0.00000000 [Extra] => ) [21] => Array ( [Field] => width [Type] => decimal(15,8) [Null] => NO [Key] => [Default] => 0.00000000 [Extra] => ) [22] => Array ( [Field] => height [Type] => decimal(15,8) [Null] => NO [Key] => [Default] => 0.00000000 [Extra] => ) [23] => Array ( [Field] => length_class_id [Type] => int(11) [Null] => NO [Key] => [Default] => 0 [Extra] => ) [24] => Array ( [Field] => subtract [Type] => tinyint(1) [Null] => NO [Key] => [Default] => 1 [Extra] => ) [25] => Array ( [Field] => minimum [Type] => int(11) [Null] => NO [Key] => [Default] => 1 [Extra] => ) [26] => Array ( [Field] => sort_order [Type] => int(11) [Null] => NO [Key] => [Default] => 0 [Extra] => ) [27] => Array ( [Field] => status [Type] => tinyint(1) [Null] => NO [Key] => [Default] => 0 [Extra] => ) [28] => Array ( [Field] => serial [Type] => tinyint(1) [Null] => NO [Key] => [Default] => 0 [Extra] => ) [29] => Array ( [Field] => serialn [Type] => varchar(64) [Null] => NO [Key] => [Default] => [Extra] => ) [30] => Array ( [Field] => date_added [Type] => datetime [Null] => NO [Key] => [Default] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00 [Extra] => ) [31] => Array ( [Field] => date_modified [Type] => datetime [Null] => NO [Key] => [Default] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00 [Extra] => ) [32] => Array ( [Field] => viewed [Type] => int(5) [Null] => NO [Key] => [Default] => 0 [Extra] => ) ) [num_rows] => 33 )
```

How do I search for "serial" if it is found  do something, if it's not found then do something else?

I have tried this

```
    if(array_search('serial',$array)) { echo "hello"; } else { echo "heheheh";}
```

and it just does not do what i want it to do ?

Comment: `serial` is a value in a sub-array. As such, `array_search()` alone will not work.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2693310/search-for-values-in-nested-array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one

```
  foreach( $array['rows'] as $array1  ){
    if( array_search('serial', $array) ){
        do something here
    }
  }
```

Comment: Yep, thanks you hit the nail on the head, I knew it was something easy just had a brain fade.

This is the code that worked for me:

    foreach( $array['rows'] as $array1  ){
    if( array_search('serial', $array) ){
        do something here break; } else { do this 
    }