# How can I search in nested arrays?

Tags: php, arrays

I have a variable which is containing these nested arrays:

```
echo $var;

/* Output:
Array(
       [0] => Array
         (
             [id] => 1
             [box] => 0
         )

       [2] => Array
         (
             [id] => 2
             [box] => 0
         )

       [3] => Array
         (
             [id] => 3
             [box] => 1
         )
) */
```

Now I would like to know, is there any `[box] => 1` in `$var`? How can I do that? Actually I can search in array by `in_array()` function, but I don't know how can I do that for nested arrays?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [array_column](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) and then [`array_search`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php):

```
$index = array_search(1, array_column($var, 'box'));
```

The return value will be `false` when there is no match.

If you don't need to know the index of the matching element, but just need to know whether there is a match or not, then you can use [`in_array`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php):

```
$match = in_array(1, array_column($var, 'box'));
```

Comment: Your definition of var has errors. You cannot use the output of print_r and use it as code. The key names cannot appear in `[ ...]`

Comment: https://eval.in/554916, I have updated my answer... the arguments to array_search were inverted.

Comment: Just for my information, when `array_search` doesn't find anything, what returns? `null` or `empty`? Is there even any different between them? Actually I'm trying to use it in a condition. `if (empty($index))` or `if(is_null($index))` ?

Comment: It is FALSE then. If getting the actual index is not needed, then in_array is more suitable.

Answer (score 2):

well, you could simply use a [foreach](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) loop, as a clear and simple way, like::

```
foreach($arr as $key => $val) {
    if($val["box"] == 1) {
        echo "Found";
    }
}
```

Comment: @stack there's nothing wrong with doing something in a basic way when it can be, i guess it depends on how you want to write your code .. :)

Answer (score 0):

There is another post ([Search for values in nested array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2693310/search-for-values-in-nested-array)) that discusses a similar problem. The accepted answer there recommends using `array_walk()`.